# Accordion getting sporadically hidden in IE 7-8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, accordion

I am using jQuery accordion on a web page. In IE 8, it gets hidden sporadically sometimes when user clicks on some other window. I am not able to get why is it behaving like this. When I inspect element in HTML developer tool I could see accordion and if I change some value in that, accordion gets visible again. Can somebody please help me to identify what is the problem? If I use debugger mode everything works correctly.

Comment: please post some code ,then we can help you easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at code carefully and observed that accordion code was added in one extra  tag but strange that only IE was not able to run it properly. So I removed that extra wrapper and its running properly now.